# How to add loader like(css loader,atomizer loader etc ) in sveltekit?

Tags: webpack, svelte, sveltekit

I am migrating from sapper to svelte kit .
In sapper i used various loader in webpack.But now in `svelte.config.js` .
Can not find how to add loader?

Comment: Any examples of your old loaders?

Comment: @cascading-jox Like css-loader,atomizer-loader.

Comment: I'm not sure if loaders are supported but you can pass plugins to vite through `svelte.config.js`.